# Write a program that outputs the total of 5-digit numbers with a five in them, but not with an 8

Tags: c++, digit

My challenge is to output the total number of five-digit numbers that have a digit 5, but no digits 8. My only two answers so far have been 0, or 90000. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;
    int counter=10000;
    int ncounter=0;
    while (counter >= 10000 && counter <= 99999) {
        int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
        counter = counter + 1;
        n1 = number%10;
        number /= 10;
        n2 = number%10;
        number /= 10;
        n3 = number%10;
        number /= 10;
        n4 = number%10;
        number /=10;
        n5 = number%10;
        number /= 10;
        if (n1 == 5||n2 == 5||n3 == 5||n4 == 5||n5 == 5)
            if (n1!=8)
                if (n2!=8)
                    if (n3!=8)
                        if(n4!=8)
                            if (n5!=8)
                                ncounter=ncounter+1;
    }
    cout<<ncounter<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you first initialize `number`?

Comment: Good point. What should I initialize it to? 90000, or 99999? Does it replace     counter for all intents & purposes, so the latter can be removed?

Comment: Do you mean you need to output 10005, 10015, 10050, 10051, 10055 but **not** 10058?

Comment: If you use it without initializing it, you're asking for trouble. I advise you to execute this code with pencil and paper (and a smaller range of numbers, e.g. 10005-10008).

Comment: Programming consists of both analysis and coding. For analysis,  you might consider summing the number of such numbers with respectively 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 "5"-digits. Like, ((5)/(1))8^4 + ((5*4)/(2*1))*8^3 + ((5*4*3)/(3*2*1))*8^2 + ((5*4*3*2)/(4*3*2*1))*8^1 + ((5*4*3*2*1)/(5*4*3*2*1))*8^0. I'm not sure if that's right, but it sounds like the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, exactly that. I'm a bit confused, especially at the if/else statements. My other option looks like this:
           `if (n1 == 5||n2 == 5||n3 == 5||n4 == 5||n5 == 5 && n1!=8 || n2!=8 || n3!=8 || n4!=8 || n5!=8)`

Answer (score 2):

(num with 5 but not 8) = (num without 8) - (num with neither 8 nor 5) = 8*9*9*9*9 - 7*8*8*8*8= 23816

Comment: Same as mine but much easier to count. :)

Answer (score 1):

Each number is a selection of 5 digits (with repetitions).

Since you cannot select the digit 8, you have 9 possible digits, so this problem is equivalent to the same problem, base 9 (instead of base 10).

If you make 1 digit a 5, there are 4 non-5 and non-8 digits remaining. The number of these can be calculated as `8^4` (because there are 8 available digits to choose from, and you need to choose 4 of these). With a single 5, there are 5 ways to position the 5, so multiply by 5.

Similarly with 2 5's, there are 10 ways to position the 5s relative to other digits.

Therefore, we have the following table:

```
number of digits==5    remaining digits    ways to position 5s
1                      8^4                 5
2                      8^3                 10 = 5*4/2
3                      8^2                 10
4                      8^1                 5
5                      8^0                 1
```

There are `5*8^4 + 10*8^3 + 10*8^2 + 5*8^1 + 8^0 = 26281` numbers `<10^5` with a `5` but not an `8`.

There are `4*8^3 + 6*8^2 + 4*8^1 + 8^0 = 2465` numbers `<10^4` with a `5` but not an `8`. Therefore, there are `23816` numbers satisfying your criteria.

Comment: Here is my code now: 

`#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int number;
 
   int counter=99999;

    int ncounter=5*8*8*8*8 + 10*8*8*8 + 10*8*8 + 5*8 + 1;
    while (number >= 10000 && counter <= 99999) {
        int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
        counter = counter + 1;
        n1 = number%10;
        number /= 10;
        n2 = number%10;
        number /= 10;
        n3 = number%10;
        number /= 10;
        n4 = number%10;
        number /=10;
        n5 = number%10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    cout<<ncounter<<endl;
    return 0;
}
`
But where does while loop go?

Comment: You didn't take the `>=10000` condition into account.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a mathematical problem. Here we have three conditions:

1. First digit is not zero, as it should be a five-digit number.
2. No digits are 8
3. One or more digits are 5

There can be numbers with one to five 5s, where first digit is or is not 5 (except for 55555). That's nine cases to count.

If first digit is not 5, it has 7 options: [1234679]; if any other digit is not 5, it has 8 options: [12346790].

Here C(5) is number of combinations to place 5s, and C(o) - to place other digits.

```
N(5).  1st?    C(5)   C(o)
1        Y     1   *   8^4
1        N     4   *  7*8^3
2        Y     4   *   8^3
2        N     6   *  7*8^2
3        Y     6   *   8^2
3        N     4   *  7*8
4        Y     4   *  8
4        N     1   *  7
5        Y     1

Sum:     23816
```